# Census data aggregated at MGRS level

Tags: demographics, census

I would like to be able to have a file with U.S. Census data pre-aggregated at some level of the Military Grid Reference System (MGRS). Ideally at thier 10km precision level, but I'd take whatever I could get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think this exists as a pre-aggregated data file.

However you could use a tool like [census_area](https://github.com/datamade/census_area) to get a close approximation. With this tool, you could download block or block group level data and aggregate them your desired geographies.

(I'm one of the authors of this library)

Comment: The library will do it for you. You'll define your grid, and the library will find all the blocks that fall within a grid cell.